# Network error named "NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1005 "The network connection was lost." comes too frequently

Tags: ios, objective-c, web-services, networking

I am facing network issue many times whenever i calling webservices.Each time it will give me error like

> NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1005 The network connection was lost.

but network conenction is exist still it gives me these errors.Also this same error is too frequent.Can any one help me in this.Here is the code i am using :

```
- (void)postRequest:(WSPostRequestType)servicetype parameters:(NSString*)parameters customeobject:(id)object block:(ResponseBlock)block
{
    if (![self isNetworkAvailable])
    {
    if (errorAlertView != nil)
    {
        errorAlertView = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"AppName" message:@"Network not reachable !!" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"ok" otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [errorAlertView show];

    }
    return;
}
NSBlockOperation *operation = [NSBlockOperation blockOperationWithBlock:^{
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{

        /******************* Set Url for WebService ********************/
        NSError *error = nil;
        NSHTTPURLResponse *response = nil;
        NSString *URLString = [[NSString alloc]init];

        switch (servicetype)
        {
            case WSUserRegistration:
                URLString = URLRegistraion;
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
        //NSLog(@"url String :%@",URLString);

        NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:URLString] cachePolicy:NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringLocalCacheData timeoutInterval:DEFAULT_TIMEOUT];
        [request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:URLString]];
        [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];

        NSData *postData;
       // NSData *jsonData;
        NSString *postLength;
        if (object == nil)
        {
            NSString *PostParamters= parameters;

            postData = [PostParamters dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding allowLossyConversion:YES];
            postLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%lu", (unsigned long)[postData length]];
            [request setValue:postLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
            [request setHTTPBody:postData];
            [request setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
        }
        else {
            postLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%lu", (unsigned long)[object length]];
            [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
            [request setValue:postLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
            [request setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
            [request setHTTPBody:object];
        }
        id   Responceobjects;NSString *responseString;

        NSData   *data = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response error:&error];
        if (data.length>0)
        {
           responseString  = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];

            NSDictionary *dictionary;

            dictionary=[NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:0 error:nil];
            switch (servicetype) {
                case WSUserRegistration:
                {
                        responseString=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[dictionary valueForKey:@"status"]];
                        Responceobjects=[dictionary valueForKey:@"data"];
                }
                break;

                default:
                break;
            }
        }
        else if(error != nil)
        {
            NSLog(@" error  from webservice parse line n0. 681  %@",error.localizedDescription);
            if(error.code!=-1005 || ![error.localizedDescription isEqual:@"The network connection was lost."])
            {
                [AZNotification showNotificationWithTitle:error.localizedDescription  controller:ROOTVIEW notificationType:AZNotificationTypeError];
            }

        }
        else if(data.length == 0)
        {
            [AZNotification showNotificationWithTitle:@"Data Not Available..!!"  controller:ROOTVIEW notificationType:AZNotificationTypeError];

        }

        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(){
            [[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] addOperationWithBlock:^{
                if ( error )
                {
                    @try
                    {
                         [ROOTVIEW dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
                    }
                    @catch (NSException *exception) {
                    }
                    block(error,Responceobjects,responseString,nil);
                    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                                                [SVProgressHUD dismiss];
                                            });
                }
                else
                {
                    block(error,Responceobjects,responseString,nil);
                }
            }];
        });
    });
}];
[operation setQueuePriority:NSOperationQueuePriorityVeryHigh];
[self.operationQueue addOperation:operation];
}
```

Here is check network available code.

```
- (BOOL)isNetworkAvailable
{
if([[NetworkAvailability instance] isReachable])
{
    return YES;
}
else
{
    return NO;
}
return NO;
}
```

My application mostly based on webservice data.So there are so many webservice call for different webservice.Thanks.

Comment: What is isNetworkAvailable.. give the code.

Comment: Check whether you are using the http or https?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to restart content and setting like following way:

```
iOS Simulator -> Reset Content and Settings -> Press Reset
```

by using this your issue will be solve.

**OR**

Instead of using `HTTPMethod` try to use `HTTPBody`. After fixing this, I hope everything will fine.

Answer (score 0):

Restart the simulator and check. If it didn't work reset your simulator and check.